# TypeScript infer return type from used arguments

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript3.0, inferred-type

I'm not sure if this has been asked under different terminology. I've got a function that takes two arguments, where both can (independently) be a `number`, `string`, or `undefined`. The returned value is statically guaranteed to be also one of those two arguments:

```
export function wideNarrow(wide:number|string|undefined, 
                           narrow:number|string|undefined){
    return isNarrowScreen() ? narrow : wide;
}
```

In some part of my app I pass two numbers to the function:

`wideNarrow(8, 0);`

However, the inferred return type is `string|number`, which shows an error with a numerical operation:

```
const extendedAreaHeight = 26;
const baseY = extendedAreaHeight + wideNarrow(8, 0);
```

`Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '26' and 'string | number'.ts(2365)`

and

`Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

It can be statically inferred that this particular call will *always* return a number, why is TypeScript not detecting it and still thinking that a string or undefined might be returned, and how can I fix it without breaking existing functionality (e.g. I may return `undefined` or `string`, `string` or `number`, `undefined` or `number` and any combination of these in other places that I call the function)?

I'm on TypeScript 3.5.2/Vscode 1.36.1.

Comment: I don't know why it can't infer it that way, but it works if you define it as a generic: `function wideNarrow<T extends number|string|undefined>(wide:T, narrow:T){ ... }`

Comment: @Thomas that seems like an answer to me, why don't you make it one.

Comment: @Thomas nope, that doesn't work. it requires both arguments to be of the same type, which doesn't cover my use case. I need to be able to use it with a string and a number e.g. `wideNarrow(25, '20%')`

Comment: Then TS won't be able to infer the proper type. It doesn't look that deep into the code. Even if I do `return true ? narrow : wide;` the typescript playground does not infer from this that the returned type will always be `typeof narrow`; return type stays a union type `typeof narrow | typeof wide`

Comment: You are totally missing the point of static typing if you are after performing arithmetics on something that can be of unlatching types at different types. Separate your intended operation for each type using type checking. 26 + "20%" is not really something you need I believe

Comment: @Thomas so, isn't there any way of doing it? I'm not a master of TypeScript but with all these types/generics/mapped types/keyof/infer etc operators I think it's very likely to be possible as the type information, in theory, can be inferred statically.

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh and I think you're totally missing the point of type inference. `26 + '20%'` is *not* something that I'm using obviously. The whole question is about making TypeScript infer return type of the function as a number when only used with numbers, which invalidates your example in the first place.

Comment: inference only happens if you check the types using type checking. Without narrowing the choices, language assumes it will be used in all the possible ways including unlatching ones.

Comment: well you can use a generic with two types `function wideNarrow<T extends number|string, U extends number|string>(wide:T, narrow:U){ ... }` but you'll still have the problem that the returned type is `string|number` when you use the function with a string and a number.

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh that's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas you beat me with a few seconds. I tried the same and it worked great: no errors when used with two numbers, errors in addition when used with any other combo, and nothing breaks with the existing combos. make it an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Thomas suggested (and I simultaneously discovered), having two type arguments with the same signature solves the problem:

```
export function wideNarrow
  <T=number|string|undefined,
   K=number|string|undefined> 
   (wide:T, narrow:K){
  return isNarrowScreen() ? narrow : wide;
}
```

The reason for having two of exact types instead of one is that they can be different as I've stated in the question. If I made it just `T` without `K` and made both `wide` and `narrow` type of `T`, it forces both `wide` and `narrow` to be of same type (e.g. both `number`s), whereas I sometimes need them to be of different type (e.g. wide `string` but narrow `number`).

*Note: If anyone really wants to know in what scenario that I need it this way, I'm using it to fill stylesheets in my React Native app where some style elements are perfectly happy with both `number`s e.g. (`width: 100` of 100 points wide) or `string`s (e.g. `width: '50%'`) for filling half of the container horizontally).*

Answer (score 2):

You can add more precise function declarations, like this:

```js
export function wideNarrow(wide: number, narrow: number): number;
export function wideNarrow(wide: number|string|undefined, narrow: number|string|undefined) {
    return isNarrowScreen() ? narrow : wide;
}
```

The function still has only one implementation, but multiple declarations, which helps the compiler. See [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) documentation section.